# how to access xml file of ssl or https type domain and store in our server using php

Tags: php, xml, ssl

I want to access an XML file stored on another domain. The domain has an SSL certificate. I want to store it in my server folder. How can I achieve this in PHP? I am able to download without HTTPS from other sites, but unable to do it with HTTPS.

```html
<?PHP
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('www.123.com/abc.xml');
    $dom->save('filename.xml');
?>
```

Comment: Can you share the URL to that file. It's needed to get the CA certificate

Comment: https://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to use Curl to download this file. There are 2 option.

1. The quick fix
2. The proper fix

The quick fix, first.

**Warning: this can introduce security issues that SSL is designed to protect against.**

set:

1. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` to false

---

```
<?PHP

$url = "https://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml";

// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init();

//Now set some options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$xml = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

//  Write the string $xml to a file, data.xml
if (file_put_contents ('data.xml', $xml) !== false) {
     echo 'Success!';
} else {
     echo 'Failed';
}
?>
```

The second, and proper fix. Set 3 options:

1. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);`
2. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);`
3. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . '\CAcert.crt');`

The last thing you need to do is download the CA certificate.

- Go to,  - http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html -> click 'cacert.pem' -> copie/paste the text in to a text editor -> save the file as 'CAcert.pem' Check it isn't 'CAcert.pem.txt'

---

```
<?PHP

$url = "https://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml";

// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init();

//Now set some options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . '\CAcert.crt');


// Download the given URL, and return output
$xml = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

//  Write the string $xml to a file, data.xml
if (file_put_contents ('data.xml', $xml) !== false) {
     echo 'Success!';
} else {
     echo 'Failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: 1st option working fine for me. Thank you.     How to store the file contents in db

Comment: Hi @VijayKumar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Also consider up voting the answer.

Comment: I think you can better ask a new question, how to store that content. That way we keep the clean.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am new To it. I clicked the check mark. But unable to click up vote as it saying I need few more points. Thank you for solving my problem.